# How to register a .Net service with a command line + parameters?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, service

I would like to be able to pass parameters in the **installation** of the service. I have modified the C# code of the class that inherit from Installer... My problem is the InstallUtil.exe doesn't work with parameters (well not as I know).

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We have the same scenario and it works. You've to pass the parameters as follows

```
InstallUtil.exe /Param1="Value" /Param2="Value" "Path to your exe"
```

Then you've to override Install method on your installer

```
public override void Install(System.Collections.IDictionary stateSaver)
{
     var lParam1 =   GetParam("Param1");
}

private string GetParam(string pKey)
{
        try
        {
            if (this.Context != null)
            {
                if (this.Context.Parameters != null)
                {
                    string lParamValue = this.Context.Parameters[pKey];
                    if (lParamValue != null)
                        return lParamValue;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
```

Comment: Just for future reference : If you pass a service name by parameter (dynamic service creation), you need to get the parameter in the OnBeforeInstall. Thank you for this answer.

Answer (score 3):

Actually it can be done with InstallUtil.exe, the .NET installer utility that comes with the .NET Framework.

Take a look at this [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Windows_Service_Installer.aspx) article.

Comment: The page is very poor, but the source code show me something interesting, +1.

Answer (score 0):

Try [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page). It's a scripting language built for installations, allows you to do all manner of complex things. Personally, I'd use it for any installation that goes beyond "Next, Next, Next". Very slick, and not all that hard to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Build and installer with either Visual Studio or something like [Wix](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wix/).  In Visual Studio, you can do a [Custom Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9k65z2d(VS.80).aspx) and pass in parameters in the CustomActionData field.